# How to hide an iframe until a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a content area in which I would like to display some text when the page first loads or when the 'biography' button is clicked. When a different button is clicked (AFT) I would like to display the content of a URL via an iframe in the content area. I'm new to coding so not really sure how to achieve this.

With my code currently the text appears but the iframe appears underneath this, but I want the iframe to replace the text when the button is clicked. The function toShow() should do this but I don't know where to start. Any help is appreciated!

HTML code:

```
    <div id="content" > 
    <script src="myJS.js"></script>
    <script> displayBiography(); </script>

    <iframe src="cwExample.pdf" name="iframe1" id="pdf"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="leftBar"> 
    <br><br>
    <button class="button" onclick="displayBiography();"> Biography 
    </button>
    <h3> Samples of Work </h3>
    <button class="button" onclick="toShow();" target="iframe1"> AFT 
    </button>
    </div>
```

JS code:

```
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var biography = "<p> Text here </p> "  
    ;

    function displayBiography() {
        "use strict";
        content.innerHTML = biography;
        var iframe = document.getElementById('pdf');
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function toShow() {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('pdf');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That successfully hides the iframe when the page loads. Now could you help me with getting the iframe to replace the text in the content area when the button 'AFT' is clicked?

Comment: On your event listener (when the AFT button is clicked), hide the text and show the iframe :) Or, if you want to toggle it, add this to the onload function: `var iframeOpen = false` Then, when you click the AFT button, do this: `iframeOpen = !iframeOpen` and set `iframe.style.display` equal to `iframeOpen`, and the `style.display` of your content to `!iframeOpen`